# Can somebody explain me why my query is not working?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime

```
select to_char(current_date,'"q'[Today]'''s date is DD-MM-RRRR"')as output from dual;
```

Comment: What kind of error message do you get?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do in `ORACLE`:

```
select to_char(current_date,'"Today''s date is" DD-MM-RRRR')as output from dual;
```

```
| OUTPUT                     |
| :------------------------- |
| Today's date is 20-11-2020 |
```

Comment: provide cotext to prevent flagging for low quality answer. EoR.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to concatenate a literal string with a formatted date:

```
select 'today''s date is ' || to_char(current_date, 'DD-MM-RRRR') as output from dual;
```

This yields:

```
| OUTPUT                     |
| :------------------------- |
| today's date is 20-11-2020 |
```